# Does CouchDB do multi-domain hosting, SSL multi-domain hosting, and is there a canonical configuration for 2 or more hosts?

Tags: ssl, configuration, couchdb

[Updated with partial answers, some more detailed questions.]

1. Does CouchDB support multi-domain hosting?
   **Yes, via [vhosts] + _rewrite(s) configuration.**
2. Does CouchDB support multiple individual httpd bind_address'es (i.e., other than 0.0.0.0)?
3. Does CouchDB do multi-domain hosting with SSL support?
4. Is there a canonical (good example) configuration for 2 or more hosts with SSL?

I'd like to know how to run CouchDB to support separate domains, several of which need SSL support for secure connections.  I googled to no avail, so I'm wondering if anyone is using CouchDB this way, or whether it's even possible.  A sample configuration file would help.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like CouchDB supports either one individual ip bind_address, or the global 0.0.0.0 bind_address.

Google led to this feature request:

http://couchdb-development.1959287.n2.nabble.com/jira-Created-COUCHDB-907-Support-multiple-ip-addresses-in-bind-address-td5604285.html

which links to this discussion (2012-03-24) which indicates --- requested feature, but no ETA:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.user/7050

So the answer to #2-4 is "No." for now.  (I.e., 0.0.0.0 is the only CouchDB solution for multiple bind_address'es.)